# How to set Font size and name in Core Text Programming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text

Below is my Code crashing on

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);
```

I am trying to set font please help me out Thanks.

```
+(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect
{

    //  CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)textToDraw;
    //  Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter

    NSAttributedString *stringRef=[[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textToDraw attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0],(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName, nil]]autorelease];

    CFAttributedStringRef currentText =(__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)stringRef;
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);// at this Line it giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CFRelease(frameRef);
    //CFRelease(currentText);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    //CFRelease(stringRef);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica", 16.0f, nil);
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentText,CFRangeMake(0, _stringLength-1),kCTFontAttributeName,font);
```

Comment: Where should i paste above line can you plz elaborate it?

Comment: its not working Passing 'CFAttributedStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFAttributedString *') to parameter of type 'CFMutableAttributedStringRef' (aka 'struct __CFAttributedString *') discards qualifiers

Comment: you should make your stringref  mutable

Comment: what i will do it replace the first two line inside you method with...............       CFStringRef string =  (__bridge CFStringRef) textToDraw;
    CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString,CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);   .............try it out

Comment: Here is my code 
int length=[textToDraw length];
    CFStringRef string = (__bridge CFStringRef) textToDraw; 
    CFMutableAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0); 
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica", 12.0f, nil);
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentText,CFRangeMake(0, length-1),kCTFontAttributeName,font);
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString (currentText,CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

Comment: set ur font after replacing string

Comment: Its crashing [NSKeyValueMethodGetter objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. CFDictionaryGetValue
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute + 263

Comment: you imported this #import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

Comment: I am setting font after replacingString but now its not crashing and also not font is same. Its not decreasing font size I am providing 10.0f now but it is same. should i Post the lines

Comment: Can you please tell me how do set "System Bold" font. Actually I am trying to create pdf file in specific format and it going to be tough according to the format

Comment: Do this..........UIFont *sysBoldFont=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.f];
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)sysBoldFont.fontName, 20.0f, nil);........